# Dependencies issues loading JavaScript dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I'm implementing a script for preventing cookies to be set by third party plugins and to do this my HTML page returns all scripts with "text/plain" type so that the browser does not initially interpret them.

Subsequently, the only script of type "text/javascript" takes all this "deactivated" scripts and replace them with their "text/javascript" variant:

```
        var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
            if (script.getAttribute('type') == 'text/plain') {
                var new_script = document.createElement('script');

                new_script.setAttribute('src', script.getAttribute('src'));
                new_script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');

                script.parentNode.replaceChild(new_script, script);
            }
        }
```

This works. The scripts are executed, but there is a dependency problem. For example, the scripts that use jQuery cannot found it also jQuery script tag is the first of the page. It seems that scripts are loaded all at once instead of waiting for events like DOM ready and DOM load.
How can I reset these events?

Comment: try using the [onload event] (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) `object.onload=function(){myScript};` on your script object.Test it, see if it works properly, and if it does set up your for loop to be a recursive function instead, which you call after the onload of the previous has triggered.

Comment: how would loading a script later instead of during pageload affect cookies?

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify `src` for your script tags. If browser encounters script tag with set `src` it loads it immediately. To avoid this issue you can keep script's url in data attribute e.g. `data-src` and later create real script tag using url from this attribute.
Your initial script tags might look similar to this one:

```
<script type="text/plain" data-src="load-later.js"></script>
```

And later you can "activate" these script tags like this:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
  var script = scripts[i];
  var scriptSource = script.getAttribute('data-src');
  if (script.getAttribute('type') === 'text/plain' && scriptSource) {
    var new_script = document.createElement('script');

    new_script.setAttribute('src', scriptSource);
    new_script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');

    script.parentNode.replaceChild(new_script, script);
  }
}
```

Here is [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/z5L0JXNgxjZOKFTMJo23?p=preview) demonstrating this approach.

Comment: Thank you! It seems it works like my version. The dependency problem is still present. jQuery is the first script listed in the <head> but a jQuery script after it returns an Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined. Another script returns Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. Why this occurs?

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle or plunk demonstrating this issue, or at least provide structure of html with script tags? It is hard to tell what might be the problem without complete code example. Plunk I referenced in my answer seems to be working fine, `load-later.js` contains jQuery code and it gets executed properly after "activating" it in `script.js`

Comment: Right! This is the example for the [unblocked scripts](http://plnkr.co/edit/afZZv8D73xYX2bfJGtki) and this is the [blocked scripts](http://plnkr.co/edit/tbCgJ2XzehFS3HgOEa3u) version. In the first all works as usual, in the latter there is an `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: Blocked scripts version is failing because when you add `script` tag with set `src` dynamically it handles loading of the file asynchronously even if file is available in browser's cache. But scripts with text content are evaluated immediately, that's why you get `$ is not defined error`. You can use `onload` event handler for script with jQuery library and only then start loading scripts depending on jQuery.  
Here is updated [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yci8bSRzxwrxI5o2tzzX?p=preview)

Comment: I need that this script will work in a universal context, with or without jQuery or other libraries, so your last plunk is not a good solution only for this specific jQuery case. There is a way to block all scripts preventively and then simulate their natural execution like the normal page load do, without throw any errors?